# How to solve an error with "unrecognized argument"?

Tags: python, argparse

I have written (with a lot of aid from my friend) a python script that allows me to:

1. Search multiple directories for files with the identical names
2. Append the absolute path to the name of the file
3. Add all the files to one directory

This was done to avoid files getting overwritten when using the `cp` command.

Recently I have tried using the script but I now get an error like this:

```
python ~/gatherfiles.py —outdir protein_files —trgfile  ./*/protein.faa`
```

error:

```
gatherfiles.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ./GCF_000374525.1_ASM37452v1_genomic.fna_dfast/protein.faa ./GCF_000463742_ASM94337v1_genomic.fna_dfast/protein.faa ./GCF_...etc.
```

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

Here is the actual script:

```
_all__ = ['gatherfiles']
import os
import glob
import shutil
import argparse

def gatherfiles(outdirpath, trgfilename):
  """
  Args:
  - outdirpath (str): A path to output directory.
  - trgfilename (str): A name of target file. Escape sequence is available (eg. '*.txt').
  """

  # make output dir
  os.makedirs(outdirpath, exist_ok=True)

  # search target file
  paths = glob.glob(trgfilename, recursive=True)

  for path in paths:
    dname = os.path.dirname(path).split('/')[-1]
    fname = path.split('/')[-1]
    shutil.copyfile(path, os.path.join(outdirpath,dname+'_'+fname))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

  parser.add_argument('--outdir', type=str, required=True, help='path to output directory.')
  parser.add_argument('--trgfile', type=str, required=True, help='name of target file.')
  opt = parser.parse_args()

  gatherfiles(opt.outdir, opt.trgfile)
```

I expect the newly-named files to be stored in an output file without being overwritten by each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your parser's argument `--trgfile` takes one string.
But you call your script with a wildcard: `—trgfile  ./*/protein.faa`.

This wildcard is then evaluated to multiple strings hence the unrecognized argument error.

Either change the trgfile to accept multiple values (add `nargs='+'`) or call your script with a single trgfile.

Comment: Will wrapping argument in quotes help?

Comment: I tried his code and it is working with wildcard. Indeed it is interpreted as a string. It is then interpreted as multiple files thanks to its glob call.

Comment: I tried wrapping the arguments in quotes and it seemed to have worked. It had slipped off my mind that the arguments are taken as string... Thank you, Taek, IcedLance and Simon

Answer (score 1):

You're running this from the shell, which does its own glob expansion. If you want to pass the argument

```
./*/protein.faa
```

to your program un-expanded, you need to escape it to protect it from the shell, eg.

```
'./*/protein.faa'
```

Alternatively, as Taek said, you can change your function and arg parser to accept a pre-expanded list of target paths.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I tried as you said and it worked!